# QtWebengine view of map leaflet?

Tags: qt, leaflet, qml, kde-plasma, qwebengineview

So i am trying to use the QtWebengineView in qml to display a map leaflet weathermap, it is not loading, but another map leaflet does work, any ideas why?

this one works

```
WebEngineView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "http://mapshakers.com/projects/leaflet-pulse-icon/"
}
```

this one does not

```
WebEngineView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "https://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&lang=en&cities=false&layer=radar&lat=29.6915&lon=-95.0474&zoom=9"
    //url:"https://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&cities=true&layer=temperature&lat=51.4552&lon=-0.1816&zoom=5"
    profile:  WebEngineProfile{
                       httpUserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
                       httpAcceptLanguage : "en-US,en;q=0.5"
                       //AllowPersistentCookies:true // not working
            }
}
```

[here is my test code qml](https://github.com/txhammer68/qml/blob/master/leaflet.qml)

Is this an issue with the owm leaflet map or qtwebengine?
Another question is how to accept cookies automatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for map leaflet

```
onFeaturePermissionRequested: { grantFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, true);code here
```